# Implementating OAuth access token in ASP.NET Web API2 webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I use ASP.NET Web API and using a jquery ajax method.

I would like to create secure Web services using OAuth access token.

How can I implement OAuth2 to ASP.NET Web API2 Web Services?

I want to prevent the use of the web services without logging in - no access token.

There is a sample project with the implementation of oauth2 to web services?

**WebApi Controller for example:**

```
public class GetDataController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(int id, string accessToken)
    {

        //Check access token
        //How can I implementing this logic for authorization valid access token
        if (accessToken == isInvalid)
        {
            return "Access denied";
        }

        //If accessToken is valid return value
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$.get( "api/getdata", { id: 1, accessToken: "KEY" } )
.done(function( data ) {
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest way would be to start from a new **Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Web Application template**. In the "*New ASP.NET Project*" dialog select "*Web API*" and then click "*Change Authentication*" button and select option "*Individual user accounts*" like the picture below:

[image: Web API Change authentication]

This will create a project that uses the new ASP.NET membership "family member" **ASP.NET Identity** with a **bearer token OAuth** implementation.

### What you need to look at are the following classes:

***App_Start->Startup.Auth.cs***

Token authentication is handled by OWIN middleware, here is the code that configures     the pipeline. The most important is the call to **UseOAuthBearerTokens** which will enable 3 OWIN middleware components Authorization Server middleware, Application bearer token middleware, External bearer token middleware. You probably won't need the last one.

***App_Start->IdentityConfig.cs***

By default ASP.NET Identity is using Entity Framework as a storage provider (user, roles,claims persistance). If you will not use EF, you have to switch to another storage provider or implement it yourself with a couple of interfaces. [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity.](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

***Providers->ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs***

OWIN middleware will handle every request with the appropriate header. Here is the code that validates username and password provided in the HTTP header against a storage provider and returns the token which you will append to every subsequent HTTP request.

### Authentication workflow

1. First you need to get the security token. This is the task of the OAuth authorization server. The token endpoint is configured to exist at `http://yourSite/Token`. To get the token you need to compose a special HTTP header (test it with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)). The first 3 lines should go to the POST request header and the last one to request body.

   ```
   Host: yoursite
   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
   Content-Length: 51

   grant_type=password&username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx
   ```

   If the credentials are ok, you will receive the following response. Save the **access_token** value so that you will use it in step 2:

   ```
   .expires=Tue, 17 Jun 2014 22:11:12 GMT
   .issued=Tue, 03 Jun 2014 22:11:12 GMT
   access_token=c-D34PHKFGaPthuF2sIwmeowXYAPFiSPsMH...
   expires_in=1209599
   token_type=bearer
   userName=xxxxxxx
   ```
2. Compose a appropriate GET request to a secured resource with jQuery (use show response to see the whole response):

   ```
   var getData = function(){
   var url = "http://yoursite/api/protectedResource/";
   $.ajax(url,{
   type: "GET",
   headers: "Authorization" : "Bearer " + accessToken
   }).always(showResponse);
   return false;
   };
   ```

I hope this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really OAuth more like stateless authentication.

Its not WebAPI but [here's a demo](https://github.com/jchannon/Nancy.Demo.StatelessAuth) using [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org) (which I prefer to WebAPI) and stateless auth